# Saving data via PUT request $resource angular.js

Tags: angularjs, rest, resources, put, ngresource

Forgive me if this has already been asked and I have missed it but this has been bugging me all weekend and I do not know what I am doing wrong. I am trying to make a PUT request using the $resource service in angular.js with the ngResource module. I am fairly new to angular so if I am making rookie mistakes again apologies... on the learning curve.

I have followed the guidelines at the bottom of the official page at the angular docs here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

I am making a GET request to my backend and pulling in a 'group' object, one of the properties of which is called 'teams', which is an empty array.

I then have functionality for a user to create a team via a form and then save it to mongodb. I automatically want the team to get added to the user group they are a part of, so I want the group object to add the team to the teams array and then perform the PUT. I have a Groups service which I am injecting as a dependency to the controller. I am doing the following:

```
app.controller('teamsController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 'Teams', 'Groups', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, $location, Teams, Groups) {

    $scope.createTeam = function () {

        var team = new Teams({.... }); //create the new team with all the data required
        var groupId = this.team.group; //get the id to pull the correct group id from mongodb

        //use Groups service to pull in the group to update, save it as a variable group

        Groups.get({groupId: groupId}).$promise.then(function(group) {
            var group = group;
            group.teams.push(team);  //push the team to the teams array in the group

            console.log(group); //This logs exactly what I am hoping for with the new team in the teams array on the group object

            //save the new team to the database, update the group by adding the new team to the teams array then go to the new team page

            team.$save(function (response) {
                Groups.update({id: groupId}, group);
                $location.path("teams/" + response._id);
            });
        });
    };
}]);
```

My team gets created how it should, and I am getting a successful 200 back from the server on the PUT request, but for some reason the team is not being added to the teams array on the group object. If I am missing something blatant... apologies in advance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my Groups service:

```
app.factory('Groups', ['$resource', function('$resource') {
    return $resource(
    'api/v1/groups/:groupId',
    {
        groupId: '@_id'
    },
    {
        update: {method: 'PUT'}
    }
);
```

Comment: looks fine. Inspect the update request with firebug or chrome devtools to check if the team is being send. In that case, the problem would be in your API.

Comment: @cuttlas According to dev tools the team is being sent in the request payload, If I use the REST client Postman to make a PUT on any of the properties on the object it updates successfully, so I think the API is working okay.

Comment: PUT implies the user is going to provide the new fully update list. PATCH would be better, as the user can just send the team to add/remove.

Comment: Not sure with resource as I've only ever used Restangular - Have you considered using this, I feel it is better than $resource

Comment: Okay I managed to figure out why it wasn't being put on, on the API I wasn't setting the value to the teams key as an id for mongo to map the team model onto the array. So I have managed to fix that, though I have encountered another issue, for some reason my team array on the group object isn't holding more than two teams, when I add a new one, the previous last item in the array gets removed.